# Difficulty with jface's ComboViewer, need help

Tags: java, swt

I have the Comboviewer object for which i am adding a list with two values say Type1 and Type2.

But while displaying it is displaying as   :   [Type1, Type2]
instead of                                 :    Type1 then below this
                                                Type2.

And i want the first one to be selected by default.

need help.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ArrayContentProvider and set the ComboViewer input as an array or list to display a list of elements. Define toString() on the element type or provide a LabelProvider object  using setLabelProvider() to control the text displayed for each item in the combo.

```
class Type
{
    private final String    m_name;

    Type(String name)
    {
        m_name = name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Type " + m_name;
    }
}

Type type1 = new Type("1");
Type type2 = new Type("2");
ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(combo);
comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
comboViewer.setInput(new Type[] {type1, type2};
comboViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(type1));
```

Comment: It's the combo widget that the ComboViewer wraps, but you could call it with the parent composite and ComboViewer will create one for you.